# req.session undefined only with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

So, I've been struggling with these for a couple of hours now. The session won't get sent to server when I use AJAX to POST something to the server, but it works fine without AJAX, like clicking links, logout, etc and this is makes me pulling my hair in frustration. Anyway, these are my codes:

```
var express = require('express'), // express 4
mongoskin = require('mongoskin'),
Busboy = require('busboy'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
session = require('express-session'),
mailer = require('nodemailer'),
compress = require('compression'), 
morgan = require('morgan'),
ect = require('ect'),
suspend = require('suspend'),
MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(compress());
app.engine('.ect', renderer.render);
app.set('env', 'development');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/admin', session({
    secret : 'qlauwork secret yo',
    name : 'qlauworks.sess',
    proxy : true,
    rolling : true,
    cookie : {
        maxAge : 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6
    },
    store : new MongoStore({
        db : 'qlauworks',
        auto_reconnect : true,
        defaultExpirationTime : 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6
    }),
    unset : 'destroy'
}));

// ... etc etc

app.post('/admin/login', function (req, res) {
    var msg = {};
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers : req.headers });
    busboy.on('field', function (fieldName, val) {
        msg[fieldName] = val;
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function () {
        suspend.run(function * () {
            msg.password = crypto.createHash('whirlpool').update(SALT).update(msg.password).digest('hex');
            var user = yield db.users.findOne({ username : msg.username, password : msg.password }, suspend.resume());
            if (!user) {
                return res.json({ error : 'Wrong username or password' });
            }
            // create session token
            var token = yield crypto.randomBytes(32, suspend.resume());
            token = token.toString('hex');
            yield db.users.update({ username : msg.username }, { $set : { token : token } }, { upsert : true }, suspend.resume());
            req.session.token = token;
            res.redirect('/admin/forms');
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('login: ', err);
                res.send('Server error');
            }
        });
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
});

// this is the logout and forms, works just fine
app.get('/admin/logout', auth, function (req, res) {
    suspend.run(function * () {
        var token = req.session.token;
        yield db.users.update({ token : token }, { $unset : { token : true } }, suspend.resume());
        delete req.session.token;
        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                res.clearCookie('qlauworks.sess', { path : '/' });
                res.redirect('/admin');
            }
        });
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('logout: ', err);
            res.json({ error : 'Server error' });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/admin/forms', auth, function (req, res) {
    res.send(formPage);
});

// and this is the auth middleware, could logout and moving around the admin page
// but req.session always undefined if comes from an AJAX request
function auth (req, res, next) {
    suspend.run(function * () {
        console.log(req.session);
        console.log('=====================================================')
        if (!req.session.token) {
            return res.json({ error : 'Invalid token' });
        }
        var user = yield db.users.findOne({ token : req.session.token }, suspend.resume());
        if (!user.username) {
            return res.json({ error : 'Invalid token' });
        }
        next();
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('auth: ', err);
            res.json({ error : 'Server error' });
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the client side

```
$.post('/api/item/new', elem, function (rep) {
    thisForm.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
    if (rep.error) {
        $('#alert-multi').removeClass('success').addClass('alert').text(rep.error);
    } else {
        $('#alert-multi').removeClass('alert').addClass('success').text('Success');
        $('input[type="reset"]').click();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            $('#preview-multi' + i).attr('src', '');
            $('#multi' + i).attr('data-image-src', '');
        }
    }
});
```

So, how do I solve this?

Comment: where is the mapping of `/api/item/view` in your server-side code?

Comment: @soulcheck it's like this `app.post('/api/item/:whatdo', auth, function (req, res) {`

Comment: please post the whole mapping, as that is the interesting part

Comment: @soulcheck I don't know if this is matters because it won't even pass the auth check but I'll post it anyway, wait a bit before I put it on pastebin.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't matter after all - see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mounted the session middleware on `/admin` but you're trying to call `/api/item/view`.

That won't work as using `express.use(path, middleware)` will invoke `middleware` only for requests whose `req.url` contains `path`.

Either mount the session middleware on `/` (by not using `path` parameter - simple `express.use(middleware)` will do), or change your ajax url to start with `/admin` (probably not something you want to do).

Comment: Holy crap, I can't thank you more than this. You just make me looks like a tool and I feel like it now. I just wasted about 6 hours looking to resolve this. Thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: Glad to be of any help. Sometimes getting another pair of eyes to look at the code helps more than spending hours looking at it yourself :) Happened to me so many times.

Comment: true that. Now I have to help someone to repay the favor :)